# Should we drop "education" from tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have some tags corresponding to various levels of education, including `secondary-education` and `undergraduate-education`. As the **name** of this site is "Mathematics Educators", the `education` bit seems like a waste of space, and I don't see the point in having needlessly long tags.

Should we delete `education` from these tags, leaving only `secondary` and `undergraduate`, say?

Answer (score 3):

I think [secondary](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secondary), [elementary](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary), etc. sounds a little odd and this is maybe not clear to new users what to expect from that (of course, there is a wiki description for it, but new user will probably first try the tags most suitable from the title).

I'm against dropping the additional information when the remaining tag is confusing. However, I think it's a good idea to drop such it when the remaining tag stands for itsself (like in [analysis-teaching](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis-teaching) $\to$ [analysis](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis)).

Comment: I definitely agree with your comment on the "analysis-teachng" tag. That needs to go or be modified. See [this post](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/59/the-analysis-teaching-tag/63#63).